# Getting attributes from JSON code with Jackson Parser

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to parse a JSON string using [Jackson JSON parser](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). The JSON code which I want to parse contains an array in which there is an object. From this object, I want to extract the `text` and `retweet_count` attributes:

```
[
    {
        "created_at": "Tue Jan 08 08:19:58 +0000 2013",
        "id": 288560667345178600,
        "text": "test tweet",
        "source": "web",
        "truncated": false,
        "user": {
            "id": 941802900,
            "id_str": "941802900",
            "location": ""
        },
        "contributors": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "favorited": false,
        "retweeted": false
    }
]
```

I tried to do it using this code:

```
JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(str);

boolean first = true;

while (jp.nextValue() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
    Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String fieldName = jp.getCurrentName();
        jp.nextToken();

            if (fieldName.equals("text")) {
            tweet.setText(jp.getText());
        } else if (fieldName.equals("retweet_count")) {
            tweet.setRetweetCount(jp.getValueAsLong());
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not getting the expected results. I think that the the problem is that inside the 'tweet' object, I have another 'user' object and when the parser encounters the `}` of the user object, it thinks that it is the `}` of the whole tweet object. Can you please tell me how can I resolve this situation?

Comment: How you get this Json response ? Please help me to get retweet count of perticular tweet ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you try to use Streaming API instead of tree model or data-binding? Latter two could result in much simpler code. For example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) // so we only include ones we care about
public class Tweet {
    String text;
    int retweet_count;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // reusable (please reuse, expensive to create)
Tweet tweet = mapper.readValue(json, Tweet.class);

System.out.println("Tweet with text '"+tweet.text+"', retweet count of "+tweet.retweet_count);
```

with data-binding. And with tree model:

```
ObjectNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
String text = root.path("text").getText();
// and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do what StaxMan suggested and model your data correctly in objects, but the fastest way I know to get the data you want is something like the code sample below.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> val = readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() { });
for (Map<String, Object>> map : val) {
  String tweet = map.get("text");
  Integer retweetCount = map.get("retweet_count");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code which would work. You need to consider the `user` fieldName and parse it separately, so the `}` of user object would not be considered as the end of the root object

```
while (jp.nextValue() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
    Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String fieldName = jp.getCurrentName();
        jp.nextToken();

        if (fieldName.equals("user")) {
            //Here the current token in BEGIN_OBJECT
            while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
              //You can use the user properties here
            }
        } else if (fieldName.equals("text")) {
            tweet.setText(jp.getText());
        } else if (fieldName.equals("retweet_count")) {
            tweet.setRetweetCount(jp.getValueAsLong());
        }
    }
}
```